# Anylogic init state block

Tags: state, init, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm developing an agent based combined with a dynamic process simulation.
The problem is that the agent state not works properly, they move, as the are in state 1, 2 or 3, but the simulation show me that they are in the init state (state0).
So how is possible that they are doing some actions that are performed by other states?

Comment: Please add more information, screenshots or code to explain the situation and also show what have you tried and what was the outcomes.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. You will need to share more details of the model setup, states, code... Impossible to help with this alone :) See some tips for good questions here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible is if all states transitions are condition-based (i.e. not timing or message-based) and all conditions are 'true' this causes the agent to move through all the states in one event, so it would appear that they visit every state but start and end every tick in state0.